# Adding android project dependency fails

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add a dependency to my Android gradle project, and keep getting the following error when building...

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Project with path 'externalproject' could not be found in project ':app'.
```

I have an external java gradle project that I would like to be built before my android app builds.

I have added this new project to my `settings.gradle` as follows...

```
include ':app' , ":externalproject"
project(':externalproject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../externalproject')

rootProject.name = 'mayapp'
```

My `build.gradle` in the app folder looks as follows...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidapp1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile project('externalproject')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change below

```
compile project('externalproject')
```

to

```
compile project(':externalproject')
```

Or better to use `implementation`

```
implementation project(':externalproject')
```